# Desreferenciar un puntero almacenado en un objeto constante en c++

Tags: c++

En la definición de la clase tengo un puntero int y me preguntaba si es correcto modificar el valor al desreferenciar el puntero cuando el objeto es constante

```
class A{
    public:
    int* valor=nullptr;
    
    A(){
        this->valor=new int();
    }
};

int main() {
    
    //construyo objet constante 
    const A objeto;
    
    //desreferenciar puntero y modificar el valor
    *objeto.valor=100;
    
    //usamos el valor modificado
    std::cout << *objeto.valor << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

No me salen errores durante compilación ni tampoco durante la ejecución y la salida es la que esperaba. Es correcto el código o es peligroso de fallar.

Comment: El objeto es constante, asi que no te dejara cambiar la direccion de memoria del puntero. Pero como el puntero no es constante, puedes dereferenciarlo y modificar el valor al que apunta. Ese es el comportamiento esperado.

Answer (score 0):

esta bien, porque lo constante es el objeto y no la variable que es parte del objeto.

Comment: Por favor se paciente y espera a tener la suficiente reputación para comentar, de momento eso del eliminaremos publicación y que leas [answer]